# Constructing PDA to accept language { 0^i 1^j 2^k | i = 2j or i = k, where i,j,k >= 1 }

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

$L = \{ 0^i 1^j 2^k \mid i = 2j \text{ or } i = k, \text{ where } i,j,k \geq 1 \}$

I have trouble about this PDA. Anybody can help me about draw this PDA?

Answer (score 0):

The PDA should start by counting the numbers of $0$s (by pushing some symbol onto the stack for each $0$ encountered) ensuring that there is at least one $0$. Then, nondeterministically choose to match each $0$ with two $1$s (by popping one symbol off the stack for every two $1$s encountered) or, ignore any $1$s encountered and match each $0$ with a $2$ (by popping one symbol from the stack for each $2$ encountered).